# AWS data pipeline name tag option for EC2 resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-data-pipeline, aws-data-pipeline

I'm running a shell activity in EC2 resource sample json for creating EC2 resource.

```
{
 "id" : "MyEC2Resource",
 "type" : "Ec2Resource",
 "actionOnTaskFailure" : "terminate",
 "actionOnResourceFailure" : "retryAll",
 "maximumRetries" : "1",
 "instanceType" : "m5.large",
 "securityGroupIds" : [
  "sg-12345678",
  "sg-12345678"
 ],
 "subnetId": "subnet-12345678",
 "associatePublicIpAddress": "true",
 "keyPair" : "my-key-pair"
}
```

Above json is creating EC2 resource using data pipeline but I want to give a name to the above resource when I will open EC2 resource in AWS console it will show EC2 resource name with other attributes, currently it's showing blank.

See attached image for more details
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **tag the instance** with:

```
 Key: Name
 Value: MyName
```

`MyName` is an example name. You need to change it to what you want it to be.

Adding the tag to the pipeline should propagate the tags to instances. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-adding-tags.html):

> Applying a tag to a pipeline also **propagates** the tags to its underlying resources (for example, Amazon EMR clusters and **Amazon EC2 instances**)

But probably it does not work retrospectively. If you already have a pipeline with instances, its unlikely new tags will propagate. Propagation usually only works at the resource creation. For existing instances you may need to use EC2 console instead.

Comment: Where is the option , I want to do with data pipeline itself not manually

Comment: @JohneDoe Adding it to your piplineline should be enough. I will extend the answer.